# MS-ACCESS How to change a textbox font color via subroutine or function

Tags: vba, function, ms-access, textbox, subroutine

I have some textboxes in a form and i set one them with these properties by default

```
txtSearchBox.Value = "Wait.."
txtSearchBox.ForeColor = 2
txtSearchBox.FontItalic = True
```

I want to add an onClick event to this txtSearchBox in order to change its properties via a subroutine or function because i want to use this sub/fun on other textboxes..

so i declared a global variable

```
Dim CurrentCtrl As Object
```

and tryed to do the job..

```
Private Sub txtSearchBox_Click()
CurrentCtrl = txtSearchBox.Name
txtWait4Input (CurrentCtrl)
End Sub

Private Sub txtWait4Input(CurrentCtrl As Object)
CurrentCtrl.ForeColor = 0
CurrentCtrl.FontItalic = False
CurrentCtrl.Value = Null
End Sub
```

but this doesn't work..

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Programmatically changing control properties affects all instances of control. If you need this to be dynamic by record then use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Object variable not set (Error 91) on the line CurrentCtrl.Name = txtSearchBox.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `Set`
2. remove parens from sub call
3. use Controls collection
4. Dim statement does not create a global variable, that requires Global or Public, Dim declares a variable that is available only to the module it is declared in
5. variable CurrentCtrl should not be declared in two locations

So if all code is behind form:

```
Dim CurrentCtrl As Object
_________________________________________
Private Sub txtSearchBox_Click()
Set CurrentCtrl = Me.Controls("txtSearchBox")
txtWait4Input
End Sub
_________________________________________
Private Sub txtWait4Input()
CurrentCtrl.ForeColor = 0
CurrentCtrl.FontItalic = False
CurrentCtrl.Value = Null
End Sub
```

Could eliminate variable in header and Set line:

```
Private Sub txtSearchBox_Click()
txtWait4Input Me.Controls("txtSearchBox")
End Sub
_________________________________________
Private Sub txtWait4Input(CurrentCtrl As Object)
CurrentCtrl.ForeColor = 0
CurrentCtrl.FontItalic = False
CurrentCtrl.Value = Null
End Sub
```